# Excel formula for searching string

Tags: excel

I am a newbie in Excel. I need a formula for searching a word and returning its match items and values.
I have a master data sheet, heading with Item code, Item Name, Qty, Price and it’s Catogory.

In my working sheet, I have only item code and item name.
I insert a search key column after the item name.

When I enter a word or phrase in a search key column, that word need to search in item name column and find and match similar items with its value from master data sheet and return all matched items in my worksheet with sort by item catogory wise.

Can you help?

Example

Worksheet

```
item code      item name     Search key 
123     Apple USA                App
124     Orangeuk.                Ora
6772    M.Water 500.          —  (Blank)
1234    Apple Ind.                ind
```

Master data

```
item code     item name.     qty   price    cat.
12525              Tissue.         12    1.3      23
124                   Orangeuk     5      1.2     12
123                  Apple USA    16      1.7   13
6772                M.water 500   2      1.0   18
1234                 Apple Ind.      5      1.7   13
```

The result (sort with cat.)

```
item code   item name   qty     price    cat.

124             Orangeuk.     5      1.2        12
123              Apple USA  16      1.7       13
1234           Apple Ind.     5       1.7       13
```

Comment: I just insert another image example to get more idea about this https://ibb.co/kDBGhR

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using **[Search Key]** instead **[Item No.]** or **[Name]** as a "look up value" in a `VLOOKUP`?

**[Item No.]**

```
=VLOOKUP($D3,$J$3:$N$12,2,0) 'VLOOKUP([Item No.],[Range Master Data],Number column to lookup, False)
```

**[Name]**

```
=VLOOKUP($E3,$K$3:$N$12,2,0) 'VLOOKUP([Name],[Range Master Data from Name],Number column to lookup, False)
```

[image]